Why does laptop Wi-Fi disconnect when power is plugged in? Works fine on battery power
My mother-in-law has a Lenovo Yoga laptop running Windows 11 home.
Her Wi-Fi works normally when running on battery power. The moment I plug in the AC adaptor, Wi-Fi stops working. Note that the laptop doesn't have an ethernet port, so I can't confirm whether the behavior also happens for wired internet.
If I start a ping running in a shell, I can watch the pings connect or stall in real time as I plug and unplug the computer.
I've tried basics like updating WLAN drivers, windows "network settings reset", forgetting networks, etc.
I can't see anything in ipconfig or other utilities to suggest what's going on and I don't know what to try next.

Check Power Options, Advanced, to see if there are different Wireless Adapter Settings or other differences between plugged in and on battery.

@DrMoishePippik no differences that I could see :-(
